# Backbone View event firing only once after view is rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

From the Router, I create a Search View with the following code:
(The `if` is to only create a `new` View where one does not already exist, since the View never changes.)

```
search: function () {
    if (!this.searchView) {
        this.searchView = new SearchView();
    }
    $('#content').html(this.searchView.el);
    this.headerView.selectMenuItem('search-menu');
},
```

In the View, I have an events hash, binding a click event to a search button:

```
events: {
    "click .search-query": "search"
},
```

This results in the **event only firing the first time the search button is used**.
Removing the `if` from the search function solves the problem.

This however does not seem to be the correct way to approach this, since the View should not need to be recreated (*reinitialized* and *re-rendered*).

#### An attempted fix:

I attempted to add `this.delegateEvents();` to the render function of the Search View as follows (while leaving the `if` in the search function), but it did not solve the problem:

```
render:function () {
    console.log('rendering search...');
    $(this.el).html(this.template());
    this.delegateEvents();
    return this;
},
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [using a single div as a container for multiple backbone views losing event bindings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10707911/using-a-single-div-as-a-container-for-multiple-backbone-views-losing-event-bindi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're not calling `render()` again, `delegateEvents` won't be called again. You can just call `delegateEvents` directly in your router. This is just an example; there are probably more elegant ways to do it.

`delegateEvents` basically rebinds the events to your view. This is useful if the html of your views gets removed from the dom. That looks like what is happening in your example.

```
search: function () {
    if (!this.searchView) {
        this.searchView = new SearchView();
    }
    $('#content').html(this.searchView.el);
    this.searchView.delegateEvents();
    this.headerView.selectMenuItem('search-menu');
}
```

Comment: The `.html()` call intentionally kills the events (further discussion [over here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10708775/479863) if you're interested), the elegant solution IMO is to create and destroy views as needed instead of trying to reuse them.

Comment: Thanks @Gohn67 , that solved it.  However, it is sometimes preferable to remove views, and recreate them where needed, and in this case, I realised that I did not need to preserve the view.

Comment: Thanks @muistooshort, for pointing this out.  Your links are definitely worth reading for anyone wondering whether to reuse or recreate elements.

Additionally, I also found the following useful info:
[Backbone.js : repopulate or recreate the view?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7567404/backbone-js-repopulate-or-recreate-the-view).

Comment: In addition, the this related answer and comments provides information on [binding and unbinding events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14041042/backbone-0-9-9-difference-between-listento-and-on/14042632#14042632).